# How to convert a REAL (32-bit float) to an 8-bit byte array in IEEE 754 representation?

Tags: plc, structured-text

I'm using Rockwell Automation Connected Components Workshop (CCW).

I need to convert a REAL type to a byte array to be sent over RS-232/ASCII. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the COP instruction.

> Copies the binary data in the source element to the destination
>   element. The source element remains unchanged.

```
COP_1(Enable:=TRUE, Src:=3.14, SrcOffset:=0, Dest:=byte_array, DestOffset:=0, Length:=4, Swap:=FALSE);
```

The disadvantage is that you will need extra code to verify COP finished before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user-defined function, say REAL_TO_754_INT (all variables are DINT, except In_f32 and norm_f32, which are REAL):

```
// Ref: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/pack2.c

IF In_f32 = 0.0 THEN
    // get this special case out of the way
    REAL_TO_754_INT := 0;

ELSE

    // check sign and begin normalization
    IF In_f32 < 0.0 THEN
        sign := 1;
        norm_f32 := -In_f32;

    ELSE
        sign := 0;
        norm_f32 := In_f32;

    END_IF;

    // get the normalized form of f and track the exponent
    shift := 0;
    WHILE (norm_f32 >= 2.0) DO
        norm_f32 := norm_f32 / 2.0;
        shift := shift + 1;
    END_WHILE;
    WHILE (norm_f32 < 1.0) DO
        norm_f32 := norm_f32 * 2.0;
        shift := shift - 1;
    END_WHILE;
    norm_f32 := norm_f32 - 1.0;

    // calculate the binary form (non-float) of the significand data
    // 23 is the number of significand bits
    significand := ANY_TO_DINT(norm_f32 * ANY_TO_REAL(SHL(1, 23)) + 0.5);

    // get the biased exponent
    // 7 is (number of exponent bits, 8)-1
    expn := shift + (SHL(1,7) - 1); // shift + bias

    // return the final answer
    // 31 is (the total number of bits, 32)-1
    REAL_TO_754_INT := OR_MASK(OR_MASK(SHL(sign, 31), SHL(expn, 23)), significand);

END_IF; // In_f32
```

Then mask and shift repeatedly to divide into bytes:

```
as_DINT := REAL_TO_754_INT(your_REAL);
message[1] := ANY_TO_BYTE(AND_MASK(as_DINT, 16#FF));
message[2] := ANY_TO_BYTE(AND_MASK(SHR(as_DINT,8), 16#FF));
message[3] := ANY_TO_BYTE(AND_MASK(SHR(as_DINT,16), 16#FF));
message[4] := ANY_TO_BYTE(AND_MASK(SHR(as_DINT,24), 16#FF));
```